# How to properly use mysqli to query and prevent injection

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So I am attempting to learn mysqli and do some database querying. I am using the class file that's found here [Simple-Mysqli](https://github.com/bennettstone/simple-mysqli/blob/master/class.db.php)

I want to make sure that I do this right to prevent any mysql injection attempts but I am having a bit of trouble.

Here's my attempt at a query:

```
$id = '1776425144629';
$query = "SELECT * FROM article WHERE type = 'lnews' AND article_id = " . $id;
$query = $database->escape($query);
$results = $database->get_results( $query );
foreach( $results as $row )
{
    echo $row['headline'] .'<br />';
}
```

When I use the $database->escape() call that's in the class file (shown here)

```
 public function escape( $data )
 {
     if( !is_array( $data ) )
     {
         $data = $this->link->real_escape_string( $data );
     }
     else
     {
         //Self call function to sanitize array data
         $data = array_map( array( $this, 'escape' ), $data );
     }
     return $data;
 }
```

It errors out on me and shows the following:

```
 Query: SELECT * FROM article WHERE type = \'lnews\' AND article_id = 1776425144629
 Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\'lnews\' AND article_id = 1776425144629' at line 1
```

So my question is, how can I pass some parameters to the sql statement, still using the escape or filter function to prevent any mysqli injections?

Comment: See prepared statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, several issues here:

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM article WHERE type = 'lnews' AND article_id = " . $id;
```

This line is the core of SQL Injection: Preventing SQL injection in a really simplified version van be described as: Do not concatenate your variables anymore.
So no more

```
 $sometext . $someid;
```

or
     "$sometext $someid"

Not allowed, simple.

So what then? You will have to start using bind variables. Your query will then look like:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM article WHERE type = 'lnews' AND article_id = ?";
$stmt=$mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param($id);
```

Also see  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php for more details (*just skip to the examples at the bottom).

Second issue (I promised several issues):

```
$query = $database->escape($query);
```

This escapes the full query. Never use on a query, only on a variable (if it needs escaping: When using variable binding: Not needed: It is implicit).

Comment: Ah, my misunderstanding on the escape process. Makes sense now. Question tho, doesn't the bind_param need to have an identifier of sorts ("s|i", $id)? And what about multiple params to bind? For example if lnews was bnews instead? Just do type = ? AND article_id = ? and then bind_params($type, $id)?

Comment: mysqli can just work with the order of the bind variables. So yes, your type=? and article_id=? is correct that way.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening because you're escaping the actual query statement. PHP is escaping the quotations, hence the " \'lnews\' ". This will stop the query from working because you're executing this statement:

```
"SELECT * FROM article WHERE type = \'lnews\' AND article_id = 1776425144629"
```

What you want to do, is escape the values being passed through instead. Use the following instead:

```
$id = '1776425144629';
$id = $database->escape($id);
$query = "SELECT * FROM article WHERE type = 'lnews' AND `article_id` = '".$id."'";
$query = $database->$query;
$results = $database->get_results( $query );
foreach( $results as $row )
{
    echo $row['headline'] .'<br />';
}
```

This should work fine.